# Need to change buddypress profile url by add_rewrite_rule

Tags: plugin-development

I have some problem with wordpress/ buddypress url rewrite

So i have a url like localhost/site/members/admin/jobs/it-job-create/
but need to make it localhost/site/members/admin/jobs/it-job/create/

so it should be it-job/create form it-job-create !!. How to fix it. Thanks

```
 add_rewrite_rule(
                'members/admin/jobs/it-jobs/create', 
                'index.php?pagename=members/admin/jobs/it-jobs-create'
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little tricky with Buddypress. They are not using the Wordpress way for rewrites. (https://buddypress.org/support/topic/custom-permalink-and-rewrite-rules-for-buddypress/) They are processing the url in their own module. If you have `members` as the Buddypress members page slug and the rest of the url is not a Buddypress module it will redirect you to 404.

There is a way to fool their url process:

```
function it_job_rewrite_bp_uri($path) {
  if(strpos($path, 'members/admin/jobs/it-jobs/create')) {
    return 'members/admin/jobs/it-jobs-create';
  }

  return $path;
}
add_filter('bp_uri', 'it_job_rewrite_bp_uri');
```

The above code is working correctly only if you process the old url correctly. If you don't want it processed by Buddypress simply return a path which is not a Buddypress url.